# hold code execution in java (inside a loop)

Tags: java, android, for-loop

How can I sleep in a loop in Swift?

```
int userI = 0; 
for (userI = 0; userI < users.size()/10; userI++ ) { 
  // do something 
  // Wait for 5 seconds.
}
```

I'm already familiar with this :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

But i don't think so its going to help in this case cause i don't wanna fire a function after i just wanna wait or hold until a loop cycle completes.

Comment: can please explain bit more

Comment: yeah sure it is @HotAppleCyber  if `java == swift`

Comment: oops :-) thanks. long day

Answer (score 2):

Use Thread.sleep()  when you want to sleep for few minutes

```
int userI = 0; //users is an array
int sleepSeconds =5000; 
for (userI = 0; userI < users.size()/10; userI++ ) { 

/// do something in this loop 
//// and after its done i wanna wait or hold for 5 seconds until loop again starts 

Thread.sleep(sleepSeconds);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going edit your logic like that.....

```
int userI = 0; //users is an array
    for (userI = 0; userI < users.size()/10; userI++ ) { 

    /// do something in this loop 
    //// and after its done i wanna wait or hold for 5 seconds until loop again starts 
}
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
   public void run() {
     // Don't do anything
  }
}, 5000); 

//Do you login here
```

**or**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
   int userI = 0; //users is an array
      for (userI = 0; userI < users.size()/10; userI++ ) { 

      /// do something in this loop 
      //// and after its done i wanna wait or hold for 5 seconds until loop again starts 
    }     
  }
}, 5000); 

// your logic after wait...
```

or you can try `Thread.sleep(4000);` inside your loop  like this

```
int userI = 0; //users is an array
      for (userI = 0; userI < users.size()/10; userI++ ) { 

      /// do something in this loop 
      Thread.sleep(4000); //4 sec
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

and if you want to stop and start on some separate threads you can also use "wait"